# Apollo: Accessing updateQuery via Props Query Option?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm studying the pubsub code in GitHunt-API and GitHunt-React. I see this code:

```
const withData = graphql(COMMENT_QUERY, {
  options({ params }) {
    return {
      variables: { repoName: `${params.org}/${params.repoName}` },
    };
  },
  props({ data: { loading, currentUser, entry, updateQuery } }) {
    return { loading, currentUser, entry, updateCommentsQuery: updateQuery };
  },
});
```

Here's the current version of it in my app:

```
const CreateIMPageWithDataAndMutations = graphql(GETIMS_QUERY, {
    options({ toID, userID }) {
        return {
            variables: { fromID: `${userID}`, toID: `${toID}`}
        };
    },
    props({ data: { loading, updateQuery } }) {
        debugger;  //<==CHECKING HERE SHOWS updateQuery IS UNDEFINED
        return { loading, updateCommentsQuery: updateQuery };
    },

})(CreateIMPageWithMutations);
```

updateQuery is coming in as `undefined`.  What do I need to do in order to access updateQuery?

Thanks in advance to all for any info.

Comment: Does it become defined later? My understanding is that `updateQueries` is currently `undefined` until the first query result is returned. Perhaps this is something that can be improved.

Comment: The code in `props` runs twice. Both times `loading` is defined, but `updateQuery` is not.

Answer (score 0):

@helfer on Slack provided the answer. Updating react-apollo to the latest version fixed it.